# Gravity forms Limit Date range

Tags: wordpress, date-range, gravity-forms-plugin

Hi there I want to limit the date range of a datepicker with the "dropdown" "date input type". I want to be able to set the start and end date manually. I am using version 1.8.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gravity Forms uses the [jQueryUI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) so you can use the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) options to restrict the date range.

There's also a [plugin](https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-limit-date-range/) (I'm the plugin author) that allows you to set the date range in the edit field options, if you don't want to code it yourself or you want to study how it's done.